# How to convert a Collection to byte array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have an `ObservableCollection<Employee>` how do I convert it into byte array[]?

The class Employee consists of,
 - EmployeeId
 - DateOfJoining
 - Age
 - Salary

The service I need to pass the collection to is expecting the data to be in byte[].
What would be an efficient way to convert observableCollection to byte[]?
Or do I just need to loop through the collection to create a byte array?

Comment: `The service I need to pass the collection to is expecting the data to be in byte[]` In what format/protocol?  BinaryFormatter is only one of the many alternatives. for ex,  int i = 1; binaryWriter.Write(i);  or Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(i.ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a Binary Formatter to serialize your collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx

```
var employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();


using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{    
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, employees);
    var byteArray = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Read(byteArray, 0, (int)stream.Length);
    // do whatever you want with the bytes now....

}
```

Comment: You could cut out the alloc of the byte array because memorystream already does that for you. ToArray (copy) or GetBuffer (direct)

Answer (score 0):

You have choices like Protobuf, Protobuf-Net, your own custom BinaryWriter "ToBytes, FromBytes". It really depends on what your receiving end desires, and whether they are using a generic documented format or a custom one.